# How to get the first Sunday of the Month given week number and year?

Tags: java

Given a week number and a year, I'd like to be able to compute the first Sunday of that month. I've cobbled together some code that "mostly", but not always, works. Not sure why it doesn't work for every example, but that's why I'm posting. :)

The code below should get the first Sunday of the year, then iterate the number of weeks (the week number) entered. When done, the code should print out that first Sunday's date.

When incorrect, the code prints the previous Sunday, not the apparently correct one.

Suggestions appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException
{
    int enteredWeekNumber = 18;
    int enteredYear = 2022;

    int doyCounter = 1;
    LocalDate firstDoy = LocalDate.of(enteredYear, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    LocalDate someSunday = firstDoy.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

    // Loop to get every Sunday by adding Period.ofDays(7) the current Sunday.
    while (someSunday.getYear() == enteredYear && doyCounter <= enteredWeekNumber)
    {
        System.out.println(" *** " + someSunday.
                format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)));
        someSunday = someSunday.plus(Period.ofDays(7));
        doyCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you identify the examples it doesn't work for?

Comment: My approach would be to find out which month that week number is in, then use the `firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)` which you already use.

Comment: there is a conflict in the *specification*: first Sunday of **Month** given **Week Number**  is not always possible or not unique (mostly a week spans two months)

Comment: Define week. Does week # 1 contain the first day of calendar year? ISO 8601 standard week? And on what day of the week does the week start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek   // Represents a week-based year and week per the ISO 8601 definition.
.of( y , w )                  // Pass your week-based year number, and your week (0-52, 0-53). 
.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )    // Returns `LocalDate`, for the date of the first day (Monday) of that year-week.
.with (                       // Adjust to another `LocalDate` object, another date.
    TemporalAdjusters         // Utility class offering implementations of `TemporalAdjuster` interface.
    .dayOfWeekInMonth( 
        1 ,                   // nth day in the month, an ordinal number.
        DayOfWeek.SUNDAY      // The day-of-week for which we want the date of the nth.
    )                         // Returns an `TemporalAdjuster` object.
)                             // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
```

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601 standard defines a year-week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) as:

- Starting on a **Monday**.
- Week # 1 containing the **first Thursday** of the calendar year.

This means a week-based year:

- Has either **52 or 53** complete weeks.
- May include a few days from the previous and/or next calendar year.

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

If your definition is the same, then I suggest adding the [*Three-Ten Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project.

### `YearWeek`

Doing so gives you access to the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( y , w ) ;
```

Tip: Pass around your codebase objects of this class rather than mere `int` values `enteredWeekNumber` & `enteredYear`. Using objects brings [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), ensures [valid values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation), and makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

### `LocalDate`

Get the date of the first day of that week.

```
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

### `TemporalAdjuster`

Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to get nth day-of-week of that month date’s month.

Fortunately, the utility class [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) gives us just such an adjuster.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 1 , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

Apply the temporal adjuster to get another `LocalDate` object. The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). We get a fresh object rather than altering ("mutating") the original.

```
LocalDate firstSunday = ld.with( ta ) ;
```

---

If you want to get fancy, you could write your own implementation of a `TemporalAdjuster` to contain this functionality. I’ll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Amazing! This worked great. Every case I looked at is correct. :) THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try something like below if your Week starts at the first day of the year

```
int enteredWeekNumber = 22;
int enteredYear = 2022;

LocalDate someSunday = LocalDate.now()
                                .withYear(enteredYear)
                                .with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, enteredWeekNumber)
                                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```

or somthing like below, if you use ISO standard

```
LocalDate someSunday2 = LocalDate.now()
                                 .withYear(enteredYear)
                                 .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear(), enteredWeekNumber)
                                 .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```